# Is it possible to read the data from different sheets in a same xlsx file?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i am using the Apache POI to read an xlsx file. i can able to read the Sheet1 data. But when try to read the Sheet2 i am getting the Sheet1 data only.

```
String strPath = "..\\Test.xlsx";
        File excelFile = new File(strPath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excelFile);

        // we create an XSSF Workbook object for our XLSX Excel File
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);


        Sheet sheet1= workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Sheet sheet2= workbook.getSheetAt(1);
```

Comment: How do you claim that?

Comment: Check this [https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/](https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/) it could helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `getSheetAt(i)`, it returns a `XSSFSheet` object, which implements the `Sheet` interface under `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel`. Consider the block of code below:

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
```

The code above should print the content of cell A1 for the first two sheets on your document. I did it myself with a test file and it worked.

Comment: `XSSFSheet` implements `Sheet` so the OP's code is correct from that aspect

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do that using apache POI https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/

This is the part where they're iterating over the different sheets

```
    // 1. You can obtain a sheetIterator and iterate over it
    Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
    System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using Iterator");
    while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
        Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
        System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
    }
```